# Android get the view inside SimpleOnGestureListener

Tags: android, listener

I want to access to the view who use a gestureListener inside a method in `GestureListener` itself.
This is my listener:

```
public class GestureSwipeListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    final Context myContext;

    // Costanti per lo swipe
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    public GestureSwipeListener(Context context) {
        myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return super.onDown(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                        && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean onSwipeRight() {
        Log.d("FLING", "right");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onSwipeLeft() {
        Log.d("FLING", "left");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onSwipeTop() {
        Log.d("FLING", "top");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onSwipeBottom() {
        Log.d("FLING", "bottom");
        return true;
    }

} // end class OnSwipeTouchListener
```

Then in my Activity I do this:

```
GestureSwipeListener gestureListener = new GestureSwipeListener(this);

GestireDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), gestureListener);


mainView = findViewById(R.id.main_view);
mainView.setClickable(true);
mainView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now I want to get the view resource (in this case mainView) directly inside the `GestureSwipeListener` to execute some animations on that view.
I want to do this because I have to repeat the same animations on every single Activity in my application. So using the code directly in `GestureListener` (in the `onSwipeRight`, `onSwipeLeft`  methods) is better for avoiding the repetition of the same code again and again.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add parameters to your SwipeGestureListener constructor like:

In your gestureListener:

```
View myView;

public GestureSwipeListener(Context context, View view) {
   myContext = context;
   myView = view;
}

public doSomethingWithView() {
  this.myView.setText("Foobar");
}
```

In your activity:

```
GestureSwipeListener gestureListener = new GestureSwipeListener(this.appContext, mainView);
...
```

**Update 1:**

```
View mainView = findViewById(R.id.main_view);
GestureSwipeListener gestureListener = new GestureSwipeListener(this.appContext, mainView);
```

Then dont forget in your GestureSwipeListener constructor:

```
View myView;

public GestureSwipeListener(Context context, View view) {
   myContext = context;
   myView = view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I've already tried to add a View parameter in the constructor but I've a NullPointerException when my ObjectAnimator set the view as the target of the animation. 
I've another question...I want to reach generic View inside the Listener by the ID. How can I do that?

Comment: If you use your mainView as parameter with initialization before you should not get an NullPointer Exception. This way works for sure, i use it also in my projects. Look at my edit for an example. It might be helpful when you post your code with that you tried to use your view as parameter. You can't reach a view by its ID outside the corresponding activity or the class, where you inflate the corresponding xml layout.

Comment: This only works for a single view set when the listener is created. It won't work for multiple views sharing the same listener. (Which is fine for the OP's question but not for what I need.)